# Bluetooth not working when I boot directly into Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bluetooth

I'm having a strange problem in Ubuntu and Windows dual boot. Bluetooth Devices are not showing when I boot directly into Ubuntu. But, when I boot into Windows from GRUB, restart it and then booting into Ubuntu solves the problem. All the devices are showing up. Windows is not having this problem anytime.

I also used to have to have different pairing key problem earlier but I managed to solve it by replacing Ubuntu's pairing key with Windows one. But this problem, I'm unable to solve. I tried all solutions from restarting Bluetooth service to reinstalling the drivers. But the issue still persists. BTW, I do not use fast startup if you may think it is the problem. I tried all the solutions from this forum regarding Bluetooth issues in Dual-boot. But none seem to work for me.

My setup details :

Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS + Windows 10 21H1

256GB SSD (5 partitions - EFI System, Microsoft Reserved, Windows, Windows Recovery, Ubuntu)

500GB HDD for storage

Broadcom BCM43142 (rev 01) Network Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself after wasting 3 hours of my precious time just for a simple issue.
In my case, the firmware patch file of Bluetooth hardware is missing which is not included in the firmware provided by Linux.

After running `dmesg | grep -i 'blue'`, I found `Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found`

I downloaded the same from a third-party GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd).

Copied the file to the Broadcom firmware folder.

`sudo cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd`

Restarting the Bluetooth service,

`sudo modprobe -r btusb`

`sudo modprobe btusb`

And restarting my PC, solved my problem.

But I still don't understand how restarting from Windows temporary solved the problem. And anyone please let me know if the firmware file from github is safe.

Hope this helps to someone struggling like me. :)